# Finding the area of the 3 squares

Tags: geometry, area

[image]

I am clueless about how to solve this. Your help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hint: the three squares have sides $\,x, 5-x, 5-2x\,$, and you know one certain point lies on the circle.

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Comment: Measleading figure....

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["Finding the total area of three squares"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3633431/409). The question provides a solution to the problem above, but asks if what happens if the arc isn't assumed to be a semicircle.

Answer (score 2):

Use coordinate geometry.
Take left bottom point of green square as origin.

Side of green square: x

Side of gray square: 5-x

Side of blue square: (5-x)-x

Centre of circle: (2.5,0)
Point on circle: (3x-5,x)
Radius of circle: 2.5

Use distance formula: $(x-0)^2 + (3x-7.5)^2 = 2.5^2$
x = 2  (x = 2.5 discarded(?) )

Hence sides are 2, 3, 1
Area sum = 14

Comment: may i ask how do you get (3x-5,0)?

Comment: Side of green square - Side of blue square